# extraer parte del texto de una variable en bash

Tags: bash, script, texto

He extraído la variable `$1` y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
echo "$1" 
import number='125818'
```

Solo quiero utilizar el numero `125818` en una url, mi duda es como hacer para quedarme con únicamente el número `125818`.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo conseguí de esta forma:

```
echo "$1" >> $LOGFILE
IMP_NUM=$1
IMP_NUM=`echo $SEQ_NUM  | awk -F "Import number=\47" '{print $2}' | awk -F "\47" '{print $1}'`
```

Lo dejo aquí por si puede ayudar a otras personas!

Answer (score 0):

entendiendo que la variable contiene el literal `import number='125818'` puedes usar GREP para buscar por un patron especifico. En tu caso, se puede utilizar un patron numerico.

podrias hacer algo como:

```
VARIABLE="import number='125818'"
echo $VARIABLE | grep -Po "[0-9]+"
```

esto ultimo te muestra solo el numero que contiene la cadena:

```
125818
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra regex que se me ocurrió:

```
numero="$(echo $var1 | grep -Po "'\K\d+(?=')")"
```

Pero sobretodo **depende del formato de tu input**, osea, de tu url. Si hay varios números, esto te puede sacar más números. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
numero="$(echo $var1 | grep -Po "^import number='\K\d+(?=')")"
```

Y así, todo lo que esté entre `import numero='<esto>'`, será puesto en la variable "número".